# When Child class override a protected member then member become access able with . operator?

Tags: java

```
package xxx.yyy;

public class ParentClass {
    protected void doPrint(){
        System.out.println("Parent.....");
    }
}


package aaa.bbb;

import cathy.inner.ParentClass;

public class Child extends ParentClass {        
    public void getName(){
        System.out.println("Child....");
    }
}
```

A client in `package aaa.bbb` can not uses `new Child().doPrint()`. But if child override the then client can use `new Child().doPrint()`.
It seems strange to me because during override we can't change the access modifier to more restrictive, but is this case inherited  method seems private.

Why this is implemented in such a manner ?

Comment: It defining a new method but it just for a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Super` class method's access modifier is `protected` and it states method would be accessible with in `class`, `package` and `subclass`.

*So it is not accessible in subclass's package*.

when you override that particular method in `subclass` with `protected` access modifier then it would accessible as `protected` methods are accessible under same `package`.

Answer (score 0):

Protected will allow only child classes to access methods... Its not a strange its one type of restriction which java have...